# Why can't this argument pack be unpacked directly into a vector initializer list?

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

I don't understand why the commented out line in the code fragment doesn't work. Additionally, what is the actual type of `vec`? It looks like it could match the initialization format of a `std::list` as well.

I've looked through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13978916/inserting-a-variadic-argument-list-into-a-vector) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51449738/unpacking-variadic-template-parameters-into-initializer-list) is what finally gave me the working solution, but now I don't understand why that works and the commented line doesn't, or how you can know the actual type (and therefore time/memory complexities of) `vec`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


template <class ...T>
void func(T... arg_name) {
    // std::vector<T> vec{arg_name...};
    auto vec{arg_name...};
    for (auto i : vec) {
        std::cout << i << std::endl; 
    }
}


int main()
{
    func(1, 2, 3, 4);
}
```

The error message I get when I uncomment `std::vector<T> vec{arg_name...}` and comment out `auto vec{arg_name...}` is

```
In function 'void func(T ...)':
8:20: error: parameter packs not expanded with '...':
8:20: note:         'T'
10:19: error: range-based 'for' expression of type 'auto' has incomplete type
```

Comment: One major problem is that `T` isn't a single type. When the compiler parses the function it doesn't know what all of `T` will be `int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`T` is parameter pack, but `vector` takes one type parameter as type of elements, you can use `common_type` to select it:

```
std::vector<std::common_type_t<T...>> vec{arg_name...};
```

Comment: It also worth mentioning that it will work without specifying the type for a `vector` at all in C++17 because of the CTAD.

Comment: If you edit to include that the type of `vec` is `initializer_list`, I’ll accept your answer. Unless I’m wrong about the type, that is.

Comment: In this case `auto vec{arg_name...};` type of `vec` is `initializer_list`. But it seems you are using old compiler, upgrade this, because proper way should be `auto vec = {arg_name...};` [see this reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction) - in the following section *Other contexts - auto type deduction*.